# tensorflow.linalg.eig throwing error UnboundLocalError: local variable 'out_dtype' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, tensorflow, linear-algebra, eigenvalue, eigenvector

I have below code

```
import tensorflow as tf
X_tf = tf.Variable([[25, 2, 9], [5, 26, -5], [3, 7, -1]])
lambdas_X_tf, V_X_tf = tf.linalg.eig(X_tf)
```

when I execute it I get below error

File "C:\Users\u1.conda\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\traceback_utils.py", line 153, in error_handler
raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
File "C:\Users\u1.conda\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\linalg_ops.py", line 406, in eig
e, v = gen_linalg_ops.eig(tensor, Tout=out_dtype, compute_v=True, name=name)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'out_dtype' referenced before assignment

What can be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `dtype as float32`:

```
X_tf = tf.Variable([[25, 2, 9], [5, 26, -5], [3, 7, -1]], dtype=tf.float32)
```

Comment: worked. I wonder why TensorFlow did not through more meaningful error.